# Saving and retrieving a DateTime in Isolated Storage using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to use the WPToolkit to implement a DateTime picker in my Windows Phone application. I'm also trying to learn MVVM while doing this. I am fairly new to both.

I'm not quite sure how to go about this, so here's my code:

```
private void LoadAll()
{
    var page = new MainPageModel();
    page.PageTitle = "";
    page.TimerOneTitle = "";
    page.TimerTwoTitle = "";

    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (isf.FileExists("DateOne"))
        {
            page.TimerOneText = "";//Open "DateOne" from iso store and set it to this value. How?
        }
        else
            page.TimerOneText = "Set the date!";
    }

    page.TimerOneText = DateOne.ToString();
    LoadHubTiles();
    LoadMainPhotos();
}

    _setDateOne = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
        {
            DatePicker picker = new DatePicker();
            picker.ValueChanged += picker1_ValueChanged;
        });

    private DelegateCommand _setDateOne;
    public DelegateCommand SetDateOne
    {
        get { return _setDateOne; }
    }

    void picker1_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        String name = "DateOne";
        {
            if (isf.FileExists("DateOne"))
            {
                isf.DeleteFile("DateOne");
            }
            using (var stream = isf.CreateFile(name))
            {
                DateOne = e.NewDateTime.Value;
                //I created "DateOne" in IsoStore, but how do I give it my DateOne value?
            }
        }
    }   

    private DateTime _dateOne;
    public DateTime DateOne
    {
        get { return _dateOne; }
        set { _dateOne = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

I know the code isn't complete, but for the purposes of my question, I believe it has enough. What I want to do in total is this:

Open a DatePicker. When the user saves the date, picker1_ValueChanged should fire. The DateTime from the ValueChanged method should be passed to my DateTime property and saved into isolated storage. Then, when I call my Load() method, I want to check isolated storage for the date time and set it to the date that's saved in iso store, if it exists.

Sorry, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the picker1_ValueChanged you can write

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("DateOneSaved",DateOne);
```

And when you are calling Load method

```
DateTime timerValue;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue("DateOneSaved", out  timerValue);
```

you can clear the value from the Isolated storage using Remove function

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("DateOneSaved");
```